# How to land or navigate to previous activity if click on back button

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-notifications

In My application i have implemented `Notification`. My Problem is if I click on received `Notification` it will redirect to the `Activity` which I have given there if I click on inbuilt Back button It will closing the application and going out.
 What I need is if I click on Back button, it should land to previous `Activity` how to set that.
Ex: If we got Facebook notifications if we click on that it will redirect to comment are like page, there if we click on back button it will redirect to Facebook main form.

Comment: Show your code how you implement notification code.And in PendingIntent the activity you have to show is the MainActivity which you are showing on tapping on notification??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to override onBackPressed method:

```
@override
public void onBackPressed();
{
 super.onBackPressed()
 Intent i = new Intent(this, PreviousActivity.class);
 i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
 startActivity(i);
}
```

If you are using eclipse, then right click on editor>>source>>override/implement method.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the parent activity which will be set in your manifest like this:

```
<activity
    android:name=".YourActivity"
    android:parentActivityName=".YourParentActivity">

    <!-- Parent activity meta-data to support 4.0 and lower -->
    <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".YourParentActivity"/>
</activity>
```

After this in your code, override the onBackPressed() method and do this:

```
NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
```

This method to navigate should be used only if your app is the owner of the current task, otherwise this method should be used:

```
Intent upIntent = NavUtils.getParentActivityIntent(this);
if (NavUtils.shouldUpRecreateTask(this, upIntent)) {
    // This activity is NOT part of this app's task, so create a new task
    // when navigating up, with a synthesized back stack.
    TaskStackBuilder.create(this)
            // Add all of this activity's parents to the back stack
            .addNextIntentWithParentStack(upIntent)
            // Navigate up to the closest parent
            .startActivities();
} else {
    // This activity is part of this app's task, so simply
    // navigate up to the logical parent activity.
    NavUtils.navigateUpTo(this, upIntent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

call function onBackPressed()

```
public void onClick() {
    onBackPressed();
}
```